# log4n logging constraint by host name

Tags: c#, log4net

Is there a way to constraint log4n appender to log messages based on host name? I want to enable logger only on production machines and disable logging n development machines.

I know that there is an easy way to log host name with property: %property{log4net:HostName}, then I could filter logged messages by this, but I want to use smtp appender and send logged messages via email and I would like to reduce number of sent emails.

Comment: A standard way would be to rise logging level, say to `warning` in the appenders declarations. Usually you would only want to log (serious) problems and not all the debug, info messages.

Comment: During development some errors are normal because developer doesn't normally have all all subprojects loaded, but at production such situation indicates serious error. So that approach won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution using custom filter:

```
public class HostFilter : FilterSkeleton
{
    public string AllowedHostsNames { get; set; }
    private IList<string> HostNamesList
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AllowedHostsNames))
                return new List<string>();

            return AllowedHostsNames
                .Split(',')
                .Select(n => n.ToUpper().Trim())
                .ToList();
        }
    }

    public override FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        var names = HostNamesList;
        if (names.Contains(Environment.MachineName))
            return FilterDecision.Accept;

        return FilterDecision.Deny;
    }
}


<appender name="SomeAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <to value="" />
  <from value="" />
  <subject value="" />
  <smtpHost value="" />
  <authentication value="Basic" />
  <port value="25" />
  <username value="" />
  <password value="" />
  <bufferSize value="10" />
  <lossy value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline%newline%newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="Logging.HostFilter, AssemblyName">
    <allowedHostsNames value="host1, host2, host3" />
  </filter>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using standard filters

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
  <Key value="log4net:HostName" />
  <StringToMatch value="hostToInclude1" />
  <AcceptOnMatch value="true" />
</filter>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
  <Key value="log4net:HostName" />
  <StringToMatch value="hostToInclude2" />
  <AcceptOnMatch value="true" />
</filter>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

or exclude filter like answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/755356

But I usually deploy different configuration files for development, test and production machines